# Record Reader Split to convert Fixed Length to Delimited ASCII file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a file which is of 128 MB so it is splitted into 2 blocks (Block size =64 MB ).
I am trying to convert a Fixed Length File to a Delimited ASCII File using Custom Record Reader class

Problem:

When the first split of the file is processed I am able to get the records properly when I see with a hive table on top of the data it is also accessing data node2 to fetch characters until the end of the record.
But, the second split is starting with a \n character and also the number of records is getting doubled.

```
Ex: 
First Split: 456   2348324534         34953489543      349583534
Second Split:
456         23           48324534             34953489543      349583534
```

As part of the record reader inorder to skip the characters which is read in the first input split the following piece of code is added

```
FixedAsciiRecordReader(FileSplit genericSplit, JobConf job) throws IOException {
if ((start % recordByteLength) > 0) {
              pos = start - (start % recordByteLength) + recordByteLength;
           }
           else {
              pos = start;
           }

           fileIn.skip(pos);
}
```

The Input Fixed Length file has a \n character at the end of each record.

Should Any value be set to the start variable as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, i have a variable length header in my Input fixed length file which was not skipped, so the position was not exactly starting at the beginning of a record instead it was starting at position (StartofRecord - HeaderLength). This made each record to read a few characters(as much as the headerlength) from the previous record.

Updated Code:

```
 if ((start % recordByteLength) > 0) {
        pos = start - (start % recordByteLength) + recordByteLength + headerLength;
    }
    else {
        pos = start;            
    }

    fileIn.skip(pos);
```